# Fastest way of interchanging 0s and 1s in a 2D list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Assume that I have a matrix:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0,], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

and I would like it to change to:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1,], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

What could possibly be the fastest way to deal with this case?

Currently, I use **for loop** in another **for loop** as following which is obviously too slow.

```
for my_row in my_mat:
   for my_val in my_row:
      my_val = 1 if my_val == 0 else 0
```

Comment: "Obviously too slow" - there's no faster algorithm. You need to look at each value in order to determine if you need to flip it => `O(nm)` in `n,m` the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: Why is this "obviously too slow"? Unless you know something about the data in the matrix, there is no choice but to touch ever element if you want to swap 0's with 1's and 1's with 0s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it's slow, but it isn't the fastest. Here are a few faster alternatives.

## Subtraction (super simple)

```
>>> [[1 - j for j in i] for i in lst]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

This eliminates the need for an `if` check. Although, this would only make sense if you have a list of 0/1s and you only want to flip those values.

---

## Bit Flips with XOR

```
>>> [[j ^ 1 for j in i] for i in lst]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

XOR operations are fast in general, so this is a good alternative, if you have positive values beyond one.

---

## `not` Inversion

```
>>> [[int(not j) for j in i] for i in lst]
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Note that this squashes non-zero values to 1. The `not` converts the integer to a truthy/falsy value, and the subsequent `int` converts `False` to `0`, or `True` to `1`.

---

If you're interested in performance of all the methods suggested here,

```
lst = np.random.choice(2, (1000, 1000)).tolist()

%timeit [[int(not j) for j in i] for i in lst]
%timeit [[j ^ 1 for j in i] for i in lst]
%timeit [[1 - j for j in i] for i in lst]

10 loops, best of 3: 175 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 89.8 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 61.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: heh, this is cute.

Comment: maybe  `j^1` is an alternative?

Comment: @trincot Oh yes! Bitwise... that should be even faster. Mind if I add it?

Comment: Not at all. Go for it ;-)

Comment: Add `int(not j)`, too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, all.

Comment: `1 - j`: 2.66 mks/loop (the fastest); `1^j`: 3.02 mks/loop; `int(not j)`: 4.67 mks/ loop.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks, I've added some of my own benchmarks as well.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for your suggestion! Interestingly, if found that it isn't as fast as the first option, but still fast nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

The fastest "algo" would be to leave your matrix untouched. Just remember in a separate flag that every value you read (or write) has to be inverted. Done.

But if you physically need to invert each value in the matrix, then there's only one "algo" for that - the one you already discovered. The rest is not about "algo", it is about the most efficient *implementation* of that "algo".